# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un JavaFX Navegador en un JPanel de Java Applicaction?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, javafx, javafx11

Buenas Comunidad estoy haciendo una app y estoy trabajando con un googlemap del navegador de java y quiero mostrarlo en un panel o en otro elemento donde se muestre (jlabel,jpanel,etc).

Hice un proyecto en java->javaAplication->un formulario--> con un boton.
este es el metodo que estoy llamando en el boton.

locate();

Quiero mostrarlo en un jpanel no en un fxpanel como esta ahora:

```
private void locate() {

String a = txtMapaBuscador.getText().replace(" ", "+");


final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1280, 720);
frame.setVisible(true);

final JFXPanel fxpanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(fxpanel);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebEngine engine;
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        engine = wv.getEngine();
        fxpanel.setScene(new Scene(wv));
        engine.load("https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + a);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo, esta documentación podría solucionar tu problema: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: i want to display it in a java swing panel a jpanel.